# Content disappearing when bsg_head(); is added to the <head> tag

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working with wordpress, when I add

```
<?php bsg_head(); ?>
```

to the header all the content on the page disappears. The formatting from the stylesheet is still applied though as it changes the background colour. Can anyone help me work out why?

single.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php bloginfo('title'); ?></title>
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<?php bsg_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container_12" id="singlepost">
    <div class="grid_12">

      <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

      <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

      <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php the_content(); ?>


      <?php endwhile; ?>


      <?php else : ?>


      <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
/*
Theme Name:
Theme URI: http://www..co.uk
Description: 
Version: 2
Author: Alex Sadler
Author URI: http://www..co.uk
*/

@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

@import url("css/grid.css");
@import url("css/fonts/fonts.css");
@import url("css/coda-slider.css");
@import url("css/jquery.fancybox.css");

body,td,th {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
body {
    background-color: #3D341A;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #CCCCCC;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-family: nexa_boldregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px;
    padding: 0px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
P {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
IMG {
    border: 0px;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
#contentwrapper {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
#header {
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 99;
}
#title h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
}
#info {
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font: normal 12px nexa_lightregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#info .headerphone {
    font-family: nexa_boldregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#slogan {
    padding-top: 350px;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000;
}
#slogan h1 {
    margin: -30px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font: small-caps 120px nexa_boldregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#slogan h2 {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font: small-caps 60px nexa_boldregular, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.block {
    height: 170px;
    width: 260px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #525055 no-repeat center center;
    float: left;
}
.portfolioblock {
    height: 210px;
    width: 300px;
    background: #525055 no-repeat center center;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.portfolioblock .rollover {
    height: 170px;
    width: 260px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: url(img/rolloverbg.png); 
    margin-top: 210px; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear; 
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.portfolioblock:hover .rollover {
    float: left; 
    margin-top: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear; 
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear; 
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
}
.portfolioblock img {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.text h1 {
    margin-left: 55px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
#socialmedia {
    text-align: right;  
}
#singlepost {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;   
}
#blog a {
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i'm aware, you need `<?php wp_head(); ?>`. Don't forget `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in your footer, before your `</body>` tag, which is generally used for plugins echoing javascript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the error reporting in php, so that you can see the exact error

Add the below code

```
<? error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

For more PHP updates visit http://www.phpsyntax.blogspot.in/